# Scipy: Nested optimization not working

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I wrote nested optimization functions that is not working properly. To be specific, my **get_v_1** always returns the initial guess. All the other functions work properly.

The code should work as follows:

1- get_v_1 takes as inputs initial guesses for **v** and **w**. It SHOULD find v with scipy.fmin_slsqp, so that v minimizes the **get_v_0** function.

2- get_v_0 takes the v from get_v_1 as input, and FOR THAT VALUE OF v it finds w so that w(v) minimizes the rss of the function w_rss.

The first part is not working. Any suggestions?

```
def w_rss(w, v, x0, x1, z0, z1):
    k = len(x1)
    importance = np.zeros((len(x0),len(x0)))
    np.fill_diagonal(importance, 1.0/len(x0))
    predictions = np.dot(x0, w)
    errors = x1 - predictions
    weighted_errors = np.dot(errors.transpose(), importance)
    weighted_rss = np.dot(weighted_errors,errors).item(0)
    return weighted_rss

def v_rss(w, z0, z1):
    predictions = np.dot(z0,w)
    errors = z1 - predictions
    rss = sum(errors**2)
    return rss

def w_constraint(w, v, x0, x1, z0, z1):
    return np.sum(w) - 1

def get_w(w, v, x0, x1, z0, z1):
    result = fmin_slsqp(w_rss, w, f_eqcons=w_constraint, bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*len(w),
             args=(v, x0, x1, z0, z1), disp=False, full_output=True)
    weights = result[0]
    return weights

def get_v_0(v, w, x0, x1, z0, z1):
    weights = fmin_slsqp(w_rss, w, f_eqcons=w_constraint, bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*len(w),
             args=(v, x0, x1, z0, z1), disp=False, full_output=True)[0]
    rss = v_rss(weights, z0, z1)
    return rss

def get_v_1(v, w, x0, x1, z0, z1):
    #result = minimize(get_v_0, v, args=(w, x0, x1, z0, z1), bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*len(v))
    result = fmin_slsqp(get_v_0, v, bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*len(v),
             args=(w, x0, x1, z0, z1), disp=False, full_output=True)
    importance = result[0]
    return importance
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the [SLSQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) algorithm uses the jacobian of the target function to estimate the next test parameter. In your case, in `get_v_1` you call `fmin_slsqp` with `get_v_0` as its target function. In turn, `get_v_0` returns a value that depends on the minimization procedure of `w_rss`.

It is clear that you can't get the jacobian of `get_v_0` analytically, thus the jacobian will be estimated numerically calling `get_v_0` with very small differences in the parameter that is being minimized. As the output of `get_v_0` depends on the minimization, it is posible that `get_v_0` returns the same value for very similar input parameter values. This would yield a zero-valued jacobian and the `fmin_slsqp` inside of `get_v_1` would think that its initial guess already is the minimum.